# iText7 (PdfSweep): System.ArgumentException: CharacterRenderInfo objects represent a single character

Tags: c#, itext7

Trying to redact some text from PDF using PDFSweep 2.0 (C#).
The following code works for most of the PDF files I have, but on some PDF files the code below throws an ArgumentException

```
String input = "G:/tmp/redact/input.pdf";
String output = "G:/tmp/redact/output.pdf";
CompositeCleanupStrategy strategy = new CompositeCleanupStrategy();
strategy.Add(new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy(@"Hello"));

PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(input), new PdfWriter(output));
PdfAutoSweep autoSweep = new PdfAutoSweep(strategy);
autoSweep.CleanUp(pdf);           
pdf.Close();
```

The full exception stack looks like this:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: CharacterRenderInfo objects represent a single character. They should not be made from TextRenderInfo objects containing more than a single character of text.
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener.CharacterRenderInfo..ctor(TextRenderInfo tri)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener.RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy.ToCRI(TextRenderInfo tri)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener.RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy.EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
   at iText.PdfCleanup.Autosweep.CompositeCleanupStrategy.EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.DisplayPdfString(PdfString string)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.ShowTextOperator.Invoke(PdfCanvasProcessor processor, PdfLiteral operator, IList`1 operands)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.InvokeOperator(PdfLiteral operator, IList`1 operands)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfResources resources)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.ProcessPageContent(PdfPage page)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfDocumentContentParser.ProcessContent[E](Int32 pageNumber, E renderListener, IDictionary`2 additionalContentOperators)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfDocumentContentParser.ProcessContent[E](Int32 pageNumber, E renderListener)
   at iText.PdfCleanup.Autosweep.PdfAutoSweep.GetPdfCleanUpLocations(PdfDocument doc)
   at iText.PdfCleanup.Autosweep.PdfAutoSweep.CleanUp(PdfDocument pdfDocument)
   at gp_redactor.Program.Main(String[] args) in G:\prj\gp_redactor\gp_redactor\Program.cs:line 70
```

I'm inclined to think this is a bug in iText, can anyone suggest a workaround?

Comment: If this is a bug in iText, I would love to see the PDF you used to generate this exception.

Comment: @JorisSchellekens
Unfortunately I'm not able to release the PDFs.  Is there anything wrong as far as the code I've posted above, or if there is another way to write it?

Comment: @Joris a possible reason: `CharacterRenderInfo` assumes its `TextRenderInfo` to have a Unicode string representation with only one character. This needs not be the case, though, it merely is clear that it represents only a single glyph, but a singe glyph may represent a longer sequence of Unicode characters.

Comment: @Joris when I copy the text from the problematic PDF and paste its contents into notepad, following characters shows up even though the PDF displayed everything in English.
 I suspect this is what is causing the exception.  In this case, is there a workaround or does iText only work with PDF with underlying unicode text?

Edit: I guess stack overflow removed the characters I tried to paste above

Comment: Thanks for the input @mkl and frostwolfer, I'm going to raise this issue within iText.